# Generate grid coordinates from PySCF DFT package for plotting grid points

Tags: density-functional-theory, python, pyscf

As can be read in the pyscf.dft documentation, there should be the possibility of generating the coordinates of the grid for numerical integration. According to the [documentation](https://pyscf.org/pyscf_api_docs/pyscf.dft.html#module-pyscf.dft.gen_grid), one can generate the coordinates with the `get_partition` function, which is part of the `pyscf.dft.gen_grid` module.

My question is the following: If the `get_partition` function returns the mesh grid coordinates and the corresponding grid weights, how can one directly access and manipulate the generated data (printing, shaping arrays, etc.)? I tried to print the grid coordinates, which are returned as an array according to the documentation, but it is not specified under which name the grid coordinates are returned.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you want to know? It seems to me like you already have the answer: `get_partition` gives you the coordinates of the grid points and the weights (returned arg 1 and 2 respectively). Is your question how to integrate quantities on the generated grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I usually do is I generate the grid with `pyscf.dft.gen_grid` as you mentioned, for example

```
def __init__(self, mol, calc):
    self._grid = pyscf.dft.gen_grid.Grids(self._mol)
    self._grid.level = 8 # level of accuracy of the grid. 8 is pretty dense, you might be OK with the default (maybe 5?)
    self._grid.build()
```

Doing this I will have access to `self._grid.coords` and `self._grid.weights`. Then all you need to do is apply whatever function you want to the coordinates and take the dot product of this quantity with the weights to do a quadrature

```
desired_quantity = apply_function(self._grid.coords)
res = self._grid.coords * self._grid.weights
```